# Easy way to get notifications using php, mysql and js

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am doing a restaurant aplication using php, mysql and js but I have a little problem.

When a client order somthing (using a tablet) I need a notification appears in another terminal but using the "easy way".

table orders:

```
id  |   id_place   |  id_meal   |   id_waiter  |   status
1   |   3          |  20        |   4          |   0
2   |   4          |  17        |   4          |   0
3   |   2          |  13        |   2          |   0 
4   |   1          |  13        |   5          |   1  <-- All these are ordes
```

I am thinking to do update.php:

```
$que = mysql_query("SELECT id, id_waiter, status FROM ordes WHERE status = 0");
$notifi = mysql_fetch_array($que);
```

And I have all the orders in a standby state (status = 0) and Now I can show the results counting the rows for each waiter:

```
Waiter2 [1]   //waiter2 has 1 notification
Waiter4 [2]   //waiter4 has 2 notifications
```

But these results have to be constantly updated every 5 or 10 sec. How can I do that? I dont want to use jnode, sockets or semething like that.

Answer (score 3):

Use the method `setTimeout()` to call a function every X seconds that will refresh the list of orders in standby
More info here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

If you don't want to reload the whole page you will have to use AJAX
More info here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 1):

In a PHP page you could use a while loop and sleep at the bottom:

```
<?php

while (someCondition) {
    //Get Data and show.
    sleep(5);
}

?>
```

You can write something in to set `someCondition` to false to stop the process when you need to as well.

Answer (score 1):

use ajax. in this case i used mootools.

```
var that = this;
var req = new Request.HTML({
        method: that.ajax.method,
        url: that.ajax.url,
        data: {'action' : 'update', 'waiterID': x},
        onRequest: function(){ /* do something */},
        onComplete: function(){ /* do something */}
        }).send();
```